# blank page while grabing xml data using php and printing it to div 

Tags: php, xml, json, session, curl

I tried this for pulling out the data from xml to php in session and printing in div but it shows blank page.. I tried it different ways.. below is another way of printing but still same result..

```
<?php
session_start();

$yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";  
$yql_query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('XAUUSD=X','XAGUSD=X','PLN12.NYM','PAK12.NYM','USDCAD=X')";  
$yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query);
$yql_query_url .= "&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env";
$yql_query_url .= "&format=json";
$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);  
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);      
$json = curl_exec($session);
$phpObj =  json_decode($json);  
if(!is_null($phpObj->query->results)){  
}  
if(!is_null($phpObj->query->results)){  
    foreach($phpObj->query->results->quote as $quotes){  
        $quotes = $_SESSION[''];
        $_SESSION['Ask'] = $Ask;
        $_SESSION['Bid'] = $Bid;
        $_SESSION['AskRealtime'] = $AskRealtime;
        $_SESSION['BidRealtime'] = $BidRealtime;
        $_SESSION['LastTradeDate'] = $LastTradeDate;
        $_SESSION['LastTradePriceOnly'] = $LastTradePriceOnly;
        $_SESSION['LastTradeTime'] = $LastTradeTime;
  }  
}  
?>
<body>
<div>
<ul>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['Ask'];?></li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['Bid'];?></li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['AskRealtime'];?></li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['BidRealtime'];?></li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['LastTradeDate'];?></li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['LastTradePriceOnly'];?></li>
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['LastTradeTime'];?></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Can any one suggest please

I even tried editing the section "foreach($...

```
foreach($phpObj->query->results->quote as $quotes){  
        echo $quotes['Ask'];
        echo $quotes['Bid'];
        echo $quotes['AskRealtime'];
        echo $quotes['BidRealtime'];
        echo $quotes['LastTradeDate'];
        echo $quotes['LastTradePriceOnly'];
        echo $quotes['LastTradeTime'];
        }
```

Thanks in advance
XML Generated by YQL

```
<query yahoo:count="5" yahoo:created="2012-05-12T21:27:10Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<diagnostics>
<publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
<redirect from="http://datatables.org/alltables.env" status="301">http://www.datatables.org/alltables.env</redirect>
<url execution-start-time="404" execution-stop-time="830" execution-time="426" proxy="DEFAULT">http://datatables.org/alltables.env</url>
<url execution-start-time="846" execution-stop-time="1256" execution-time="410" proxy="DEFAULT">http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml</url>
<url execution-start-time="1464" execution-stop-time="1465" execution-time="1" proxy="DEFAULT">http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=aa2bb2b3b4cc1c3c6c8dd1d2ee1e7e8e9ghjkg1g3g4g5g6ii5j1j3j4j5j6k1k2k4k5ll1l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8nn4opp1p2p5p6qrr1r2r5r6r7ss1s7t1t7t8vv1v7ww1w4xy&s=XAUUSD%3DX,XAGUSD%3DX,PLN12.NYM,PAK12.NYM,USDCAD%3DX</url>
<query execution-start-time="1262" execution-stop-time="1465" execution-time="203" params="{url=[http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=aa2bb2b3b4cc1c3c6c8dd1d2ee1e7e8e9ghjkg1g3g4g5g6ii5j1j3j4j5j6k1k2k4k5ll1l2l3mm2m3m4m5m6m7m8nn4opp1p2p5p6qrr1r2r5r6r7ss1s7t1t7t8vv1v7ww1w4xy&s=XAUUSD%3DX,XAGUSD%3DX,PLN12.NYM,PAK12.NYM,USDCAD%3DX]}">select * from csv where url=@url and columns='Ask,AverageDailyVolume,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,BookValue,Change&PercentChange,Change,Commission,ChangeRealtime,AfterHoursChangeRealtime,DividendShare,LastTradeDate,TradeDate,EarningsShare,ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid,EPSEstimateCurrentYear,EPSEstimateNextYear,EPSEstimateNextQuarter,DaysLow,DaysHigh,YearLow,YearHigh,HoldingsGainPercent,AnnualizedGain,HoldingsGain,HoldingsGainPercentRealtime,HoldingsGainRealtime,MoreInfo,OrderBookRealtime,MarketCapitalization,MarketCapRealtime,EBITDA,ChangeFromYearLow,PercentChangeFromYearLow,LastTradeRealtimeWithTime,ChangePercentRealtime,ChangeFromYearHigh,PercebtChangeFromYearHigh,LastTradeWithTime,LastTradePriceOnly,HighLimit,LowLimit,DaysRange,DaysRangeRealtime,FiftydayMovingAverage,TwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage,ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage,Name,Notes,Open,PreviousClose,PricePaid,ChangeinPercent,PriceSales,PriceBook,ExDividendDate,PERatio,DividendPayDate,PERatioRealtime,PEGRatio,PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear,PriceEPSEstimateNextYear,Symbol,SharesOwned,ShortRatio,LastTradeTime,TickerTrend,OneyrTargetPrice,Volume,HoldingsValue,HoldingsValueRealtime,YearRange,DaysValueChange,DaysValueChangeRealtime,StockExchange,DividendYield'</query>
<javascript execution-time="260" instructions-used="302744" table-name="yahoo.finance.quotes"/>
<warning>Unable to sort response according to field 'Ask,Bid,AskRealtime,BidRealtime,LastTradeDate,LastTradePriceOnly,LastTradeTime'.</warning>
<user-time>1525</user-time>
<service-time>837</service-time>
<build-version>27222</build-version>
</diagnostics>
<results>
<quote symbol="XAUUSD=X">
  <Bid>1585.30</Bid>
  <AskRealtime/>
  <BidRealtime/>
  <LastTradeDate>5/11/2012</LastTradeDate>
  <LastTradePriceOnly>1580.3002</LastTradePriceOnly>
  <LastTradeTime>5:15pm</LastTradeTime>
  <Ask>1575.30</Ask>
</quote>
<quote symbol="XAGUSD=X">
  <Bid/>
  <AskRealtime/>
  <BidRealtime/>
  <LastTradeDate>5/11/2012</LastTradeDate>
  <LastTradePriceOnly>28.858</LastTradePriceOnly>
  <LastTradeTime>5:39pm</LastTradeTime>
  <Ask/>
</quote>
<quote symbol="PLN12.NYM">
  <Bid/>
  <AskRealtime>1478.60</AskRealtime>
  <BidRealtime>1462.90</BidRealtime>
  <LastTradeDate>5/11/2012</LastTradeDate>
  <LastTradePriceOnly>1465.30</LastTradePriceOnly>
  <LastTradeTime>5:02pm</LastTradeTime>
  <Ask/>
</quote>
<quote symbol="PAK12.NYM">
  <Bid/>
  <AskRealtime>0.00</AskRealtime>
  <BidRealtime>0.00</BidRealtime>
  <LastTradeDate>3/23/2012</LastTradeDate>
  <LastTradePriceOnly>658.80</LastTradePriceOnly>
  <LastTradeTime>7:12am</LastTradeTime>
  <Ask/>
</quote>
<quote symbol="USDCAD=X">
  <Bid>1.0005</Bid>
  <AskRealtime/>
  <BidRealtime/>
  <LastTradeDate>5/11/2012</LastTradeDate>
  <LastTradePriceOnly>1.001</LastTradePriceOnly>
  <LastTradeTime>5:55pm</LastTradeTime>
  <Ask>1.0015</Ask>
</quote>
```

I Want to grab all the Ask, Bid, AskRealtime... value from all < quote symbol=".." >

Comment: This is the result you're getting back from Yahoo for the query you generate: {"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes"}}

Comment: @Ansari so what you suggest.. sud we pay for getting the stock data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line before curl_init

```
$yql_query_url .= "&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env";
```

If you do this, the returned data will be properly parsed into $phpObj. 
The reason why you get a blank page now is because you never set the $Ask, $Bid, $AskRealTime, etc. variables - but you assign them to your session variable.

To fix that, delete this line:

```
$quotes = $_SESSION[''];
```

and change each of the following lines to be like this:

```
$_SESSION['Ask'] = $quotes->Ask;
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do or how you're trying to store the data - these session variables as they are will be overwritten every iteration of the loop. Anyway, that's your business. I've shown you how you can extract the data properly. You can figure out how you want to store it.

Comment: It worked after a month of struggle and your great help.. but it only fetched the data of USDCAD, i dont see GOLD , Silver, Platinum, Palladium datas.... I also want to display the all data from the $yql_query = "select * ..... ('XAUUSD=X','XAGUSD=X','PLN12.NYM','PAK12.NYM','USDCAD=X')